# Rescaling matrix W in Random Fourier Features

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, fourier-transform, random-fourier-features

I came across this beautiful idea of Random Fourier Features by Rahimi and Recht while working on optimising my GP model using Predictive Entropy Search.

I understand the overall idea of approximating a NxN kernel matrix using finite random features. The kernel's Fourier dual needs to be properly scaled such that it represents a normalised density function. However, I am not clear on what does the scaling mean and how does it relate to the kernel that is being approximated. Explicitly, how does the scaling factor multiplied to matrix `W` relate to the exact kernel's hyperparameters?

The scaling factor is treated differently in implementations.

For example, in the [source code by Hernández-Lobato](https://bitbucket.org/jmh233/codepesnips2014/src/ac843ba992ca1879190a472ac20c83a447e4e2c0/sourceFiles/sampleMinimum.m#lines-12), this `W` is scaled by the lengthscale `l`:

```matlab
l = 1 ./ gp_rec.cf{ 1 }.lengthScale.^2;

% We draw the random features

W = randn(nFeatures, d) .* repmat(sqrt(l(i,:)), nFeatures, 1);
b = 2 * pi * rand(nFeatures, 1);
```

There is also a great [tutorial](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/12/23/random-fourier-features/) on RFF written by Gregory Gundersen, in his implementation, the `W` is scaled by `sigma` instead of lengthscale `l`:

```py
Z    = norm * np.sqrt(2) * np.cos(self.sigma * W @ X.T + B)
```

I follow the idea that

$2/D * \cos(\mathbf{\omega}^T \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}) * \cos(\mathbf{\omega}^T \mathbf{x'}+\mathbf{b}) = \exp(i\mathbf{\omega}^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'))$

A Gaussian kernel has the form $\sigma^2\exp(- \frac{\tau^2}{2l^2})$, in rff we work with the form $\exp(-i w \tau)$ and its z-map has the form $c\cos(wx+b)$.

It is not clear how $\sigma$ and $l$ are related to $w$ or $aw$. Because $w$ is inside $\cos$, and such scaling $\cos(aw)$ is not linear, for example $\cos(2x) \neq 2\cos(x)$ in general. Similarly, $\cos(2x)*cos(2x) \neq 1/4\cos(x)*cos(x)$, while the approximation is $c \cdot cos(wx+b)*cos(wx+b) = k(\cdot)$ = $\sigma^2\exp(- \frac{\tau^2}{2l^2})$...

and my questions are:

1. what does it mean if we scale the `z` by means of scaling the `W` by a scalar `a`? i.e.  $z_{\omega}(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{2}\cos(a \mathbf{\omega}^T \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}) $.
2. how does $\exp(i\mathbf{\omega}^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'))$ link to the exact kernel and its hyperparameters such as `sigma`(variance) and `l`(lengthscale)? In other words, how does the scaling factor `a` relate to the set of hyperparamters $\sigma$ and $l$?

Or do I in fact misunderstand the intention here?

Thank you.

Comment: There’s no need to add supplemental information labeled “edit”. Instead, write a clear, coherent question about what you want to know without any extraneous information. Anyone who wants to read earlier drafts can look at the revision history.

Comment: Hi @Sycorax, Thank you for the advice. I edited the question again :)